# Jenkins pipeline not respecting a lock on a stage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins version: 2.319.3

Lockable Resources plugin version: 2.18

I have a simple Jenkins pipeline that runs based on a webhook. This pipeline runs very frequently, so we have a lock on one stage so that it won't run on multiple builds at the same time. The problem is, we noticed that infrequently, multiple builds *will* run at the same time, despite the lock. Here's the code:

```
node("Windows_Server") {
    properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])
    
    stage("Setup") {
        some stuff...
    } // end 'Setup' stage

    stage("Stage 1") {
        lock("Stage 1") {
            withCredentials(some stuff...)
        } // end lock
    } // end stage
} // end node
```

Both builds ran at *almost* the same time (maybe 0.5 seconds apart), and it appears that the first build didn't set a lock:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage 1)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
some stuff...
```

This is the second build:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage 1)
[Pipeline] lock
Trying to acquire lock on [Stage 1]
Resource [Stage 1] did not exist. Created.
Lock acquired on [Stage 1]
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
some stuff...
```

Then in Blue Ocean, the output shows that the stage for those builds ran within a few milliseconds of each other; one started at `[2023-01-25T21:39:34.917Z]`, the other at `[2023-01-25T21:39:35.040Z]`.

So my question is, why would the first one not put a lock on that stage, or if it did why did the second one not see the lock?

Comment: I have no idea. Please add your Jenkins version and version of Lockable Resources plugin.

Comment: @zett42 added. Jenkins: 2.319.3 ; lockable resources: 2.18